# Disable all symbologies Cognex Dataman

Tags: c#, c++, cognex

Is there a way to turn off all symbologies by one SendCommand? Because now I turn them off one by one, but as I know, depending on the scanner model, the number of symbologies may differ. Or probably get all supported symbologies and turn them off. I can't find it in documentation. Also in GUI for dataman you have an option to disable all of them by click on button, are they making it like me?

Comment: Have you tried to get in touch with Cognex technical support ? They're probably better equipped to answer this then SO.

Comment: @nick I thought about it, but I had a hope that I was inattentive) thank you